# Why use Modernizr if browsers ignore CSS they don't understand?

Tags: html, css, modernizr

I've been working with [Modernizr](http://modernizr.org) and it is a wonderful resource, just a great project.  However, the way I've been using it is:

- Design with baseline (IE) CSS
- Enhance with CSS3 effects for advanced browsers

Unless I was going to completely replace the styles based on behavior, why shouldn't I just add styles such as box shadows, gradients and border radii to the stylesheet?  If the browser doesn't understand a rule, it will just ignore it, correct?  And if JavaScript is off, I can't use it anyway.

Should I be using the above method in the typical case, and Modernizr for advanced cases?  Or is there something wrong with relying on browsers to ignore what they don't understand?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use (html 5) elements that some browsers do not support yet. Also you can specify fallback styling.

A lot of browsers create their own CSS rules for things like text-transform. With Modernizr you can write one rule and Modernizr makes it happen for multiple browsers.

I think it's just convenience.

Comment: That's a great point - no need to mess with -webkit, -moz and -khtml extensions and have to think about what browsers support which CSS3 features.  I don't know why that didn't occur to me.

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/codler/jQuery-Css3-Finalize to add in the prefix if you're using JS anyhow?

Comment: Problem with Javascript solutions like this is when the user turn off javascript. Better way to do browser specific stuff is server side, it is faster, cachable and more reliable. I have done this and it works perfectly. Just write your CSS in for example Firefox and don't worry about other browsers because the CSS will be automaticly translated!

Answer (score 16):

You're totally right that older browsers completely disregard much of what's in CSS3.

Because of that, I do my css3 in my basic selectors.. but often make use of the modernizr's no-feature classes to handle the older browser case:

```
div.box { 
         height:50px; 
         -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555; 
         -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px #555; }

div.box span.fakeshadow { 
         display:none; 
}

.no-boxshadow div.box span.fakeshadow { 
         display:block; background: url('fakeshadowbg.png'); 
}
```

I hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: Coming from one of the creators of Modernizr, I'd have to say, yes, that makes it more clear.

Excellent example, too.  All 3 cases I was concerned about(capable browser, older browser, older browser with JavaScript off) are handled and the site degrades gracefully.